# R recursively run an unknown sized nested loop

Tags: r, recursion

I am not sure if this is possible, but I thought I might post it anyway. Currently I am trying to write a code that will run a nested sort. The problem is, I don't know how many nested loops will need to run, it can vary from 2-7 sorting criteria.

Each loop of the function creates a data set that the lower loops will then use. I know this needs to be done using recursion, but I am having an extremely hard time getting this to work. Any help would be appreciated!

```
library(abind)
re <- c(5,5,5)
answer = matrix(0,5,5)
for(a in 1:4){
    answer <- abind(answer,matrix(0,5,5),along=3)
}

for( i in  1:re[1]){
    first <- c(1:re[1])
    for(j in 1:re[2]){
        if(j %in% first == 1){
            second = j
        }
        print(second)
        for(k in 1:re[3]){
            if(k == second){
                answer[k,j,i] <- k
            }
        }
    }
}
answer
```

## Output

```
answer
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    2    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    3    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    4    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    5

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    2    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    3    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    4    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    5

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    2    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    3    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    4    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    5

, , 4

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    2    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    3    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    4    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    5

, , 5

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    2    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    3    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    4    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    5
```

Comment: I haven't looked carefully at your code, but you might look into `while` loops and/or the `break` option instead of `for(...) if (...) x`. I don't see any random outcomes in your code so I guess you do know the size of the loop, eh.

Comment: this is just a demonstration of what it would be doing, not the actual code. There could be as many as 7 loops.